# jQuery AJAX Redirect Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to redirect to `localhost:3000/app` after I successfully triggered a DELETE method. The DELETE is successful, but I get a `DELETE http://localhost:3000/app 404 (Not Found)`. I'm assuming that this is happening because I am declaring a DELETE type and it is carrying this into the done potion of my call. Is there a better way to GET redirect?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#annotation-delete-link').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    url: '/app/edit/{{annotation.annotationId}}'
                }).done(function() {
                    window.location.href = '/app';
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: are you using twig? why don't use something like `window.location.href='{{ path('route_to_app') }}'`?

Comment: I'm using Nodejs. It isn't my url setup because it is requesting the right page path, but it is trying to make a DELETE request for it, which is why I'm receiving the issue.

Comment: Are you using `type` instead of `method` because you're using an older version of jQuery?

Comment: No, I just noticed that this was commonly used in each of the answers I read on stackoverflow.